# Sounds not working?

Tags: sound, microphone, speakers

I just installed Ubuntu on my computer alongside Windows 10, but whenever I try to use the speaker or mic nothing comes out or in. What can I do?

Comment: open settings, click sound, take a screenshot, upload it to http://imgur.com

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/6gnEG

Comment: click Headphones Playback - do you hear sound through them?

Comment: No, I don't hear sound through them

Comment: Are you install third party software like ``Media Codecs``?

Comment: What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -L` and `pactl list sinks`? You should also run `alsamixer` and assert that all the relevant audio channels have the volume turned up and aren't muted (with `00` below them instead of `MM`).

Answer (score 1):

Install `pavucontrol`. Best way to see what devices your PC can find, and unmute them.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```